# push a string from one array(with string and number) within an array to a new array depending on the value of the number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to do as much as possible myself.  First how do i call one element from an array within an array.  Then how do i push one element from an array within an array to a new array. Ultimately I want to create new arrays based on age groups. 0-20, 21-30, 31-40, 41-50, 51-60.  Print the new arrays with name and age.

```
const arr1 = ['Sarah',37];
const arr2 = ['Mike', 32];
const arr3 = ['Bill', 25];
const arr4 = ['Chris', 24];
const arr5 = ['Joe', 44];
const arr6 = ['Jesse', 33];
const arr7 = ['Jon', 28];
const arr8 = ['Michael', 55];
const arr9 = ['Jill', 59];
const arr10 = ['Helia', 4];

const mainArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8, arr9, arr10];

const newArr = [];
const age3040 = []

newArr.push(mainArr[[0][0]]);

const checkAge = (ageCheck) => {
    if (arr1[1] > 30 || arr1[1] < 41) {
   age3040.push(arr1[0]);
}
}

console.log(arr1);
console.log(newArr);
console.log(age3040);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `if` `else if`, and you should use `&&` not `||`

like this:

```
let age020 = []
let age2030 = []
let age3040 = []
let age4050 = []
let age5060 = []

mainArr.forEach(arr =>{
  const age = arr[1]
if(age >= 0 && age <= 20){
    age020.push(arr)
}else if(age >= 30 && age <= 40){
    age3040.push(arr)
}
//... do same to other age range 
})

console.log(age020)
console.log(age3040)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues in you code

1. `ageCheck` is not used at all
2. `||` should be `&&`
3. function `checkAge` is not called so you won't get the result

Here is an example for you, hope it helps.

```
const arr1 = ['Sarah', 37];
const arr2 = ['Mike', 32];
const arr3 = ['Bill', 25];
const arr4 = ['Chris', 24];
const arr5 = ['Joe', 44];
const arr6 = ['Jesse', 33];
const arr7 = ['Jon', 28];
const arr8 = ['Michael', 55];
const arr9 = ['Jill', 59];
const arr10 = ['Helia', 4];

const mainArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8, arr9, arr10];

const reuslt = [{
    range: '0-20',
    names: []
}, {
    range: '21-30',
    names: []
}, {
    range: '31-40',
    names: []
}, {
    range: '41-50',
    names: []
}, {
    range: '51-60',
    names: []
}];

for (let index = 0; index < mainArr.length; index++) {
    const item = mainArr[index];

    if (item[1] > 0 && item[1] <= 20) {
        reuslt[0].names.push(item[0]);
    } else if (item[1] <= 30) {
        reuslt[1].names.push(item[0]);
    } else if (item[1] <= 40) {
        reuslt[2].names.push(item[0]);
    } else if (item[1] <= 50) {
        reuslt[3].names.push(item[0]);
    } else if (item[1] <= 60) {
        reuslt[4].names.push(item[0]);
    }
}

console.log(reuslt);
```

Comment: I tried your code and the result is: Array(5) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object].  This just creates a single array 'names' ordering the names based on age?   Thank you

Comment: That's weird, I got the right result. How do you run the code? Can you try to run the code on chrome DevTools console ?

Comment: Or you can set a break point on the last row to see the result. I think the env you are running does not support console.log an array with details.

Comment: const reuslt and the following code creates a detailed array with groupings based on age?

Comment: Yes, result[0].range  shows '0-20', result[0].names is an array with one name 'Helia' for example.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're facing here is you don't have a way to create new groups of people as you're iterating over your list and are forced to hardcode new variables like `const age3040 = []`. Typically, you'd use an object to be able to achieve this so you can end up with an object like such.

```js
const ranked = {
  "20": ["Helia"],
  "30": ["Bill", "Jon"],
  // and so on
}
```

Which you might recognize as a tallying problem. In that case the only thing left to do is figure out which category people go into after you calculate what you need.

```js
const ranked = {}

for (const [name, age] of mainArr) {
  // a function that decides what key to give the person in that age bracket
  const tier = decideTier(age)
  const people = ranked[tier]
  if (!people) {
    // if a previous person with this age has not been seen before you'll
    // have to create a new array with the person in it so that you can
    // push new names in it the next time
    ranked[tier] = [name]
  } else {
    people.push(name)
  }
}

console.log(ranked["20"])
```

An example of the thing you're looking for here is called `groupBy` btw and can be found in libraries like [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy).